# How to move SimpleSocket server into a background process

Tags: python, python-2.7, daemon

I have a simple `socketServer` that works perfectly on the main thread.

```
#Server PORT
PORT = 8020
#reassign variables
Handler = Server #this is a SimpleHTTPHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

I need to have this run in the background and have the ability to stop the process at will. What is the proper way to do this?

**EDIT**

Sorry I was unclear. I need to have the server running non stop and I can only access the system from SSH so I can't just start it and walk away.

Comment: On what operating system are you running your script? Please add the corresponding tag. Are you using bash? If so, please add the corresponding tag.

Comment: CentOS 6.6. Well, NIX only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are running your script on a POSIX operating system and your script is named `socket_server.py`, you can use `nohup` like this:

```
$ nohup python socket_server.py >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

That will put your script in the background, make it immune to hangups, and you can exit your SSH session. The shell will print out the job number and PID:

```
$ [1] 1234
```

You can stop it later by getting sending a SIGTERM using `kill`:

```
$ kill -SIGTERM 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need threading/_thread

```
def server():
    ....

import _thread
_thread.start_new_thread(server, ())
```

This basically starts the server function on a different thread.

**EDIT:**
In this case in your `def server():` you a global variable `threadIsRunning`, if this is valued to `True` it should continue, but if it is valued to `False` run `thread.exit()` this should all be in some sort of loop.

Comment: I edited the answer. Didn't see your comment for a while.

Comment: I have to start the server with SSH. the server dies when I exit the terminal.