# Best way to run a pyramid pserve server as daemon

Tags: daemon, pyramid, httpserver, python-daemon

I used to run my pyramid server as a daemon with the `pserve --daemon` command.

Given that it's deprecated, I'm looking for the best replacement. [This link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pylons-devel/GYFvqraywBo) recommends to run it with `screen` or `tmux`, but it seems too heavy to just run a web server. Another idea would be to launch it with setsid.

What would be a good way to run it ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41335348/3657941

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move SimpleSocket server into a background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334729/how-to-move-simplesocket-server-into-a-background-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to install supervisord and setup a conf file for the service. The program would just be `env/bin/pserve production.ini`. There are countless examples online of how to do this.

The **best** option is to integrate with your system's process manager (systemd usually, but maybe also upstart or sysvinit or openrc). It is very easy to write a systemd unit file for starting pserve and then it will be started/stopped along with the rest of your system. Log files are even handled automatically in these cases.

Comment: I have found supervisord to be a great solution for running/managing pyramid and other custom server sockets. One detail to be aware of is that after restarting the server, you will need to issue the command `supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf` to "remove the stale socket".

Answer (score 4):

**Create a service file in /etc/systemd/system.** Here a example (pyramid.service):

```
[Unit]

Description=pyramid_development
After=network.target

[Service]
# your Working dir
WorkingDirectory=/srv/www/webgis/htdocs/app
# your pserve path with ini
ExecStart=/srv/www/app/env/bin/pserve /srv/www/app/development.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Enable the service:**

systemctl enable pyramid.service

**Start/Stop/Restart the service with:**

systemctl start pyramid.service

systemctl restart pyramid.service

systemctl stop pyramid.service